# copy file from one folder to another folder using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file path like this `\\ptrisf02\group2\Engine_Follow\V2500-A5\V2500-A5_e-Archive\EV15159-02\Pictures_INC\INCOMING-LX\Oil tank.jpg` in my database. I want to copy it another folder like `T:\\Temp\\` when the button clicked in my jsp page. Is there any method to do this using javascript or jquery? I tried `ActiveXObject` but it gives me this error `Automation server can't create object` in IE.

Comment: you cannot do this in client side with javascript or jquery. you can use ajax to send a command to the server and then you can do this in server side. for ajax you can see this tutorial: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

There are two main issues you are going to run into with trying to use JS in any flavour:

1. Permissions and security.
2. JS is sandboxed.

The better way would be to use JS to fire an Ajax call which does the file copy/move for you using whatever server side language the web server is based on. That is provided that the web server actually has the permission to do so.

Comment: OK,I understand. So is there any sample code or tutorial?

Comment: Personally, there are security concerns with this and will need to be understood if this webpage or application is available to the general public. For starters, if you pass the whole filename and location, both source and destination, then miscreants will be able to move sensitive files to the webroot directory and take a look at them from there. Better to pass in the part of the filename that is unique to each file required and have the destination set on the server side.

Comment: Ok, I understood. Thank you.